# Magento 2: changes to default.xml in custom theme aren't loaded

Tags: magento2, theme, custom-theme, default.xml

My custom theme is not loading any data from `default.xml`.

I confirmed this by checking the mage file in `var/cache` directory.

Can anyone please help me by explaining the cases in which `default.xml` doesn't reflect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that the type of your theme is changed to virtual.

You can check the same in table `theme`. 
The value in `type` column has to be 0.

0: Physical

1: Virtual

2: Staging

Comment: thx a lot, same thing here in local dev (dump prod database and re-import in local without changes...). I was looking for the answer since a long time cause my theme works fine in production server !